# How to put a image in HTML?

Tags: html

I am going to learn HTML. And I want to put my image from gallery to my web. How do I do that?

Please correct this code if I'm wrong because the image from my gallery is not displaying to my webpage.

Code:

```
<img src="/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20190717_104912.jpg" alt=" "/ >
```

Comment: The HTML is correct so not exactly clear what you are asking. (Obviously `src` should point to location of the file for it to render, but usage itself is fine).

Comment: `/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20190717_104912.jpg` needs to point to a valid file. Do you have a folder called `storage` at the root level of your website? Assuming this is a live website, has the image been pushed to the server as well?

Comment: He did not display.. To my web.. How do I display it

Answer (score 1):

`/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20190717_104912.jpg` looks like a file path on an Android phone; it's probably not right. If you end up deploying your HTML file at http://site.example/index.html then the browser will try to fetch http://site.example/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20190717_104912.jpg which probably isn't your Android phone.

The best thing to do is to copy the image to the same place as your HTML file and then refer to it this way:

```html
<img src="IMG_20190717_104912.jpg">
```

Here's a couple of other tips about your markup:

First, `img` is what's called a self-closing tag; you do not need to write `/>` at the end. You might see that sometimes in books from a period in the early 2000s where some people thought HTML might become an application of XML; that did not pan out. It is harmless to write `/>` but it is not useful so don't do it. (Note that if you *do* want to make your HTML be XML, I think you need to write `/>` with no space between them.) If you're learning HTML and see `/>` in it, try to find a more up-to-date resource to learn from.

Second, "alt" text is very useful to humans and machines, so use it; but if you have no useful content don't put a space in there—that's not useful.